# Question on encrypted DNS over Quic? How is it encrypted?

Tags: networking, dns, tcp, protocols

Suppose,I am using DNS over Quic. Since it is an encrypted protocol as it claims. My question is if intermediate servers cannot see my dns query, how will my dns query be resolved?
It says that the query is encrypted between client and the server. So how will my resolver know which authoritative server to forward this query to?

Answer (score 1):

QUIC is transport layer encryption, not query encryption. It is similar to DNS over HTTPS or DNS over TLS, in that the connection to the configured (usually recursive) DNS server is encrypted.

How this DNS server then resolves the DNS query (i.e. by accessing other DNS servers) and the security of this process is not part of DNS over QUIC. How the authoritative server for a specific domain is determined is the usual DNS mechanism, not specific to QUIC.